# Fastest way to convert php associate array to string

Tags: php, arrays

What will be the fastest and best way to convert the following PHP associate array to a string without json.

array

```
 Array ( [0] => A [1] => S [2] => G)
```

to a string, exactly like

```
String =  "A, S, G";
```

Most of the solutions available are using JSON, that I don't want to use. plus I want to know the "Fastest" and "Best" way.

Comment: @Rizier123  Most of those solutions are json, that I can't use. plus, I want to know the 'Fastest' and best way.

Comment: Why not consider the accepted answer to that duplicate question? What makes you believe that it isn't the fastest and best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the implode function:

`$str = implode(array('a', 'b', 'c'));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`implode()`

And read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score -1):

One way is using print_r(array, true) and it will return string representation of array

Comment: Sure, but this will _not_ produce the result the OP specifically asks for.